# Missing Colleague

Tags: colleagues, resignation, united-kingdom

I have a strange situation that I need some advice on.

I work for a small marketing agency as a senior web developer. Last week a junior developer in my team resigned. He was still in his probation period so only had to give 7 days notice, he appeared to be leaving us amicably.

This is where things start to go a bit weird.

He was fine and well on Friday afternoon when we left the office and he was excited to be involved in the live deployment of a website he'd been working on for the coming Tuesday.

On Monday morning he emailed myself and my line manager informing us that he would be a bit late that morning as some trains were cancelled and others were running late. By lunchtime he still hadn't appeared and the train company website indicated that the earlier problems had been resolved.

We tried calling him to check on his progress and a revised ETA. There was no answer on his phone and it kept ringing out. We have also tried texting him and sending him messages on WhatsApp but have received no response. The WhatsApp messages are listed has having been delivered but not read.

He didn't re-emerge on Tuesday morning which prompted us to call his emergency contact number, which went to voicemail after a long period of ringing. He still hasn't shown up today and there is still no response on his or other updates on his social media accounts.

Now I realize that he could have just decided he didn't want to work his notice and is ignoring us but there is a small chance that he may have had an accident or something while on route to the office. Basically we are just worried about his well-being and want to know that he is OK.

As an employer what is the most appropriate way to handle a missing employee?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it is really a question about a missing person, not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: Would it be inappropriate to check his home address? Just in case something really bad has happened?

Comment: Actually @Kozaky in a old job, managers would sometimes have to do exactly that. It was a job where guys could easily of been injured on and site and if no one knew/found them, things could be really bad. The 'lone worker' system would alert if they hadn't made contact in X hours, and through escalations we'd make contact. A number of times we had someones manager going out to their house at 3am just to check they had in fact got home safely! (It was a 24/7 role, where they could be called out to a site at any time).

Comment: @DavidK What obligations, if any, an employer has if an employee seems to have gone missing isn't a workplace question?

Comment: @DavidK we have a duty of care to our staff safety. I want to know if we have executed all reasonable paths to check on him and that further pursuit wouldn't be illegal.

Comment: @BSMP and user5451386, Asking about legal obligations will be different for every country and is entering the legal scope that is also off-topic here. For legal obligations you should ask your company lawyer.

Comment: @DavidK From the [tag:united-kingdom] description: "Questions about the workplace that may specifically relate to cultures, customs, or **laws** in the United Kingdom."

Comment: Since the answer was closed while I was writing an answer, if you are in the US, call the local police and ask for a well check visit.  I don't think they tell you anything, but they will check to make sure he's ok.

Comment: @Burgi Certain legal topics are allowed here, specifically those that any HR professional would be expected to know the answer to, for example laws about discrimination or employee privacy. An employee going missing is uncommon enough that I wouldn't expect your average HR person to know what the legal obligations are. See [this Meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice) for more details.

Comment: @DavidK It wasn't clear to me that this was a legal question before the OP's last comment and their new edit. I agree that it's off topic now.

Comment: This is definitely off topic now.  My answer has been deleted.

Comment: The edit changed the frame of the question to being purely legal, which is off topic per Workplace SE's definitions. Voting against the reopen flag.

Comment: This could be a very useful question if edited to bring it into line with the site's scope.  I have made an attempt at such an edit now.  I urge you to consider voting to re-open the question.

Comment: Even if this was not closed as off topic, I would be inclined to close it as a duplicate of https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111044/50529 since that question covers this.

Comment: @anketam I think that question was (rightly) closed as being too broad, whereas this question has a clear scope that is answerable and helpful to future users.

Comment: @Lumberjack but in order to answer this question, wouldn't you have to answer all the individual questions in that duplicate question? I agree with you that it would be great to get this in scope but I'm having trouble thinking about the best way to do that without the risk of it becoming too broad and/or a duplicate

Answer (score 8):

You can try checking online presence, if you know any of his usernames/handles. If he posted on e.g. Facebook, reddit, Stack Overflow, etc. then he is probably simply ignoring you. Some platforms (such as Stack Overflow) also list a "last seen at" date on the profile.

Other than that, the best course of action is to try the emergency contact again, and if that fails inform the police.

The exact response will vary on locality; we had a similar situation a few years ago (in the Netherlands) and the police entered the coworker's apartment with the landlord's key. They didn't find him, but did report that there are "signs that he is not in any danger". They didn't give us more information out of privacy concerns.

> there is a small chance that he may have had an accident or something while on route to the office. Basically we are just worried about his well-being and want to know that he is OK.

If that happened then, presumably, some bystanders called an ambulance and he is being taken care of. The risk is that something happened *at his home* and that no one has noticed yet.

Comment: If the ex-staffer in question is actually on SO, maybe we will soon see a "I went dark after quitting, and now my prior employer is stalking me, what do I do?" question...